# User being prompted to download "userAppPanel"?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a script that basically asks the user to select the store that he wants to use.  The way it works is that the script reads all the UserGroups, creates a UiInstance that contains:

- A label that describes what action is expected
- A list of radio buttons, one for each store
- A submit button with a serverHandler.

These elements are contained in a verticalPanel.

When the code reaches the

```
doc.show(app);
```

It shows an empty UiInstance, and after a few moments, a Save As dialog appears.

(Don't have enough rep to post the attachment)

Clicking Cancel doesn't do anything.

This pc is running Chrome 18.0.1025.168 m, the same version that I use to develop the script...which runs perfectly on my machine.

Any ideas on what's going on?

---

Edit: Well, although it doesn't really make sense (to me) I think I've figured it out. If the running user is in a different domain than the user that created the script, you get the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this error when I forget to return the UiApp.

When you're seeing this error, is it on the initial display of the application or after you trigger another function (like clicking a button)?

If it's the latter (after an action), instead of `doc.show(app);` use `return app;`  In a spreadsheet Ui, you still need to use `doc.show(app);` the first time, but subsequent updates to the app should use return app;

Comment: It's a function called from a menuItem.  I put just in case `return app;` after the  `doc.show(app)` line, but the error still persists.  However, I just copied most of the code to a new spreadsheet, and the form displays fine...

Comment: Mhm... it looks like this has something to do with who the owner of the document is! Now... why would that affect it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. However, Juan Pablo, I don't think it is related to coming from different domains, since for me it happens in the same domain. It seems to be linked indeed to whether the person running the script is the owner or not. Pain in the ass. Let me know if you find a workaround :)

EDIT:

More details about this after a few tests. It seems it is due both to user triggering the script to execute, as well as characteristics of the trigger :
- if the function is called from a custom menu in a spreadsheet, everything works fine for everyone
- as said above, if function is called onOpen(), everything works fine for everyone
- if an installable onEdit or onOpen trigger has been set on the function, then everything works fine for the person who set it, and bad for others.
The last behavior is observed whether that person is owner or not.

Basically it seems the only times when it doesn't work well is when someone opens or edits a spreadsheet and the function is triggered by an installable trigger installed by somebody else.

This is a pain.